# Python 2.7 - Can't simulate Windows events while Task Manager is shown

Tags: python, winapi, mouseevent, keyboard-events, taskmanager

I use win3api to simulate mouse events. 
For example:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import time
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN)
time.sleep(0.05)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP)
```

For unknown reason, when the Task Manager is shown, these events will be ignored. This doesn't happen only when the Task Manager window is in focus, but when it's window isn't minimzed.

Any suggentions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to activate the program as an adminstrator. This should work.